# How to change passport to use email instead of username for authenticating?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I wanna use user's email and password for logging in.
But in passport you should use username.

I've tried many examples about how to do that. But non worked.
The real problem is when application wants to save the record into database. 
Although I have change the code to look for email not username field, this is the final record saved to database:

```
'name': 'joseph',
'username' : 'example@gmail.com',
.
.
```

But I don't want the email to be save as username.
And when I change it with mongoose after user registration it would be correct but again the problem will come when app wants to authenticate user.

It will look for username field in database not email. Because user will provide email as the username, login will fail.

Code:

```
app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
   var newUser = new User({
    username :  req.body.username,
    email :  req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name
  });

  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', "An error ocurred, please try again.");
      return res.redirect('back');
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
        req.flash("success", "Welcome");
        res.redirect("/admin");
      });
    }
  });

});
```

This code register user the way I want, but the problem is about login:

```
router.post('/login', middleware.outLoggedIn, passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/admin",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: "Invalid username or password",
    successFlash: "Welcome!"
}));
```

It always fails, because it will get user email provided in login form, then it'll compare it with the one in database. And since I have saved the user with email and username, it will compare the provided email in login form with username field in database. AND FAIL.

This is the user in databse:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5901cc5c0256ed17b4d61960"),
    "salt" : "---",
    "hash" : "---",
    "username" : "joseph320",
    "email" : "example@gmail.com",
    "name" : "joseph",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

(Login form requires email and password)

I have also done this:

```
passport.use(new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email'
}, User.authenticate()));
```

I really appreciate it if you can show me how to fix that.

Comment: Not quite an answer but it may fix your problem. I believe your very last code snippet should end with `User.authenticate));` without calling the function.

Comment: Use it instead of validPassword function?

Comment: No. Your last line has `User.authenticate()` which will immediately call the function. I believe you want just `User.authenticate` so you can pass the function to passport. It would also help if you included the `User.authenticate` function in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Can you provide more of your code? Some context is important here, such as which npm modules you're using to read and write to your database.

** **If you are using `passport-local-mongoose`**

You said you are using mongoose, and it looks like you might be using `passport-local-mongoose` on top of that. If this is the case, you can look at the options for `passport-local-mongoose`. This also includes a `usernameField` option, which indicates where you want the "username" to be stored. The usage for that would look like this:

```
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'email'})
```